# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AFNetworking":

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods, afnetworking, xcode11

I would like to update my AFNetworking to version **pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0'**, but I am getting the following error.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AFNetworking":
  In Podfile:
    AFNetworking (~> 4.0)

    AFOAuth2Manager was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      AFNetworking (~> 2.2)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AFNetworking/NSURLConnection":
  In Podfile:
    AFOAuth2Manager was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
      AFNetworking/NSURLConnection (~> 2.2)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `AFNetworking/NSURLConnection (~> 2.2)`.
```

I am using pod version 1.8.4 and macOS 10.15.3 with xcode11.3.1.
Could you please help me on how to solve the issue

Comment: Did you find a solution??

Comment: @AjithKumar.Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, changing to

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0.1'
```

and removing an outdated dependency

```
# pod 'AFNetworking+RetryPolicy', '~>1.0.3'
```

was sufficient to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue with help from AFNetworking contributor

Please go through the following link

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4567#event-3368598218

I have updated my podfile like the follwing:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :source => 'https://github.com/ElfSundae/CocoaPods-Specs.git'
pod 'AFOAuth2Manager','~> 3.0'
```

Comment: Have you made any changes in existing code to make API work... As after doing above changes to pod file I get timeout for all the implemented API requests ! anything to make it work would be helpful.